# Font and background color not applying to my table

Tags: html, css

I have a table which I want a black background and white text, some reason it's defaulting to white background and black text. What have I done wrong here?

```
#title{
font-family: Arial;
font color:#ffffff
background-color: #000000
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the HTML code for table??

Comment: Please provide html structure since we cannot see what elements you are targeting

Comment: `font color` is not a valid CSS rule, but `color` is. Also, terminate each rule with a semi-colon `;` - you don't need this for the last rule in the set but the way you have it now, the `background-color` rule will never be considered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dash and two semicolons are missing:

```
#title{
    font-family: Arial;
    color: #ffffff; // semi-colon here
    background-color: #000000; // semi-colon here
}
```

Comment: oh........... why the heck did I miss that!
Thank you.
I think I should go back to bed again and start over!